# consumer.poll not fetching records from Kafka Topic having 3 partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, producer-consumer, kafka-consumer-api

Note: Kafka version used: `kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1`

I have 1 topic named `test-kafka` which as `3 partitions` and `1 replication factor` and this topic has some string data i.e. `key and value pair` in each partition.

when I am trying to fetch records via consumer api, `consumer.poll` function isn't fetching any record and giving `records.count =0` however when I use the same logic with just a `single parition` then it works well and fetches the record.

What I thought was that Kafka will internally take care of multiple partitions and will get me the records one by one from each partition and I just need to `subscribe` to a `topic`.

Anyone can help here ?

Code snippet for reference:

```
KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));

        while(true)
        {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);

            System.out.println(records.count());

            for(ConsumerRecord<String,String> record: records)
            {
                System.out.printf("Key: %s, Value = %s", record.key(), record.value());
            }

        }
```

Above code is returning `"zero"` in records count.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a longer poll interval. I tried 100 ms with my topics but the call timed out before any messages could be retrieved. Changing to 1000 ms worked for me.